# PubNub setup with Swift Xcode 7 beta 6

Tags: swift, pubnub, xcode7-beta6

I have setup pubnub with swift using a pods and a bridging header. In the `ViewDidLoad` of my `ViewController` I'm attempting to initialise it and it fails at

```
client?.subscribeToChannels(["My_Channel"], withPresence: false)
```

It is ultimately failing in `PNClientState.m` at:

```
- (NSDictionary *)stateMergedWith:(NSDictionary *)state forObjects:(NSArray *)objects {

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableState = [([self state]?: @{}) mutableCopy];
```

This had been working fine for days so it is confusing why it would suddenly fail?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: We'll have an answer for you shortly - stay tuned.

Comment: can you add a little more context? How does it "fail" is it a null pointer exception? Is there any console output you can add? Did you implment didReceiveStatus? is that being called?

Comment: @josh k - can you answer Fred's questions and submit them to support@pubnub.com ?

Comment: @josh k - is this still an issue for you?